# Is there a way to change the variable used in a function while in a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm taking computer science courses at my school I need to figure out some code for an exam, I need to change the variable name after I print it in a for-loop after decoding RLE. It's hard for me to explain but I hope you understand.

I've tried to look it up online but I can't find the proper way to phrase the problem I have.

```
import re

def decode(string):
    return re.sub(r'(\d+)(\D)', lambda m: int(m.group(1)) * m.group(2), string)

ch=int(input())

for x in range(0, ch):
    globals()['line%s' % x]=input()

for x in range(0, ch):
    print(decode(['line%s' % x]))
```

The result I'm looking for is after entering the RLE line by line (`ch` is the amount of lines), the function I made takes the variable names created by the for loop (so their names are `line0`, `line1`, `line2` etc... until `line(ch)`) and then proceeds to decompress and print the RLE but I cant seem to get it to work

Edit: I might have made my problem not obvious and I apologize, I want to fix the last two lines of code so that the RLE is decompressed and printed in one for loop, I don't know if this is possible but I just want to know how (if) I can somehow make `print(decode(['line%s' % x]))` work, so like the variable `line` followed by a number gets changed while in the variable. Sorry I'm terrible at explaining things.

Comment: Why adding to globals? Add inputs into a list, loop over list and feed data to 
 decode  - this looks abusive - poor python.

Comment: what is input & expected output?

Comment: @J  _decoding RLE_ : "5e" -> "eeeee" - some kind of reverse run length decoder

Comment: Don't create lists of variables like that. Use a real list!

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables with sequential names like `line0`, `line1`, `line2`, etc. you should just use a list. Other dynamic variable names should be dictionaries.

Comment: @J the input is line by line RLE so line0 is 12b04a17c , line1 is 10r04y and so on, the output expected if for each to be decompressed and printed. Sorry for my poor explanation skills.

Comment: Seriously, sequentially named variables are a bad idea. Use a list so you can simply refer to `line[0]`, `line[1]`, ... `line[x]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating variable names on the fly is almost always the wrong thing to do. You just need a simple *list* of values:

```
lines = []
for x in range(ch):
    lines.append(input())

# or as a list comprehension,
# lines = [input() for x in range(ch)]

for x in lines:
    print(decode(x))
```

Comment: I see the error of my ways now, i was horrifically over complicating things and should have just gone with the simple solution. Thank you so much @chepner !!!!